# ACL (openldap2.4) for subtree won't work for specific group

Tags: openldap, access-control-list

Here's a sample ldif of my implemented ACL:

```
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
objectclass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectclass: olcFrontendConfig
olcaccess: {0}to dn.subtree="ou=someou,dc=somedc,dc=somedc" by group.exact="cn=adminwrite,ou=groups,ou=someou,dc=somedc,dc=somedc" write by * read by anonymous none
olcaccess: {1}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth manage by * break
olcaccess: {2}to dn.exact="" by * read
olcaccess: {3}to dn.base="cn=Subschema" by * read
olcdatabase: {-1}frontend
olcsizelimit: 500
```

A user belonging to group
"**cn=adminwrite,ou=groups,ou=someou,dc=somedc,dc=somedc**" 
should be able to write subtree "**ou=someou,dc=somedc,dc=somedc**", but he isn't. I can't get what's wrong with this ruleset. I also tried changing the order.

User's DN is:
**cn=manager,ou=users,ou=someou,dc=somedc,dc=somedc**

User's is in memberUID-Attribute of group:
**cn=adminwrite,ou=groups,ou=someou,dc=somedc,dc=somedc**"

Could someone give me a hint? I'll need several different users for several subtrees.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the wrong database entry. You probably want something like `dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config`.

If you've got more than one real suffix configured you can figure out which one with `ldapsearch -b cn=config olcsuffix=dc=example,dc=com dn`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works as intended now. Now I'll find out, what {-1}frontend does ;o)...